# Solubility of Cubic Equation over $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$

Tags: cubics, function-fields

Hello fellow mathematicians,

I have the following problem: Let $u_1X^3 + u_2Y^3 + u_3Z^3 - cXYZ = 0$ be a homogeneous cubic equation, where the coefficients $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$ and $c$ are in $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$. When looking for solutions we can assume that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are in $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$ and that $\operatorname{gcd}(X,Y,Z) = 1$. I am trying to find a condition on the solubility of this cubic equation. Or more specifically, the non-solubility of the equation. What we can do is the following: consider a suitable chosen prime ideal $P$ and reduce the equation modulo this prime ideal. My questions are: is there a way to determine which prime ideal to take? And, how would we determine solvability of the equation modulo $P$. We can ofcourse brute force all the possibilities as there are only finitely many of them, but that quickly gets out of hand. To illustrate the problem, consider

\begin{equation}
t^2X^3 + Y^3 - 2t^2Z^3 - 2tXYZ = 0
\end{equation}
over $\mathbb{F}_7[t]$. Reducing this modulo $(t+3)$ yields:

\begin{equation}
2X^3 + Y^3 - 4Z^3 + 6XYZ = 0.
\end{equation}
Going through all $7^3$ possibilities we see that this has no solution and hence the original equation has no solution.

Any help/reference would extremely helpful!

EDIT: I am following the paper: ELEMENTARY 3-DESCENT WITH A 3-ISOGENY by HENRI COHEN AND FABIEN PAZUKI. I try to find function-field analogues for the statements in chapter 5 of this paper.

Comment: More often than not you can probably show that $Z=0$ won't give any solutions. Thereafter the brute force part is simplified by dehomogenizing to $Z=1$.

Comment: Another trick (saving much less) is to use the symmetry that if $(X;Y,Z)=(x,y,1)$ is a solution, then so is $(\omega X,\omega^2Y,1)$ with $\omega$ a third root of unity. This is available when $3\mid q-1$, and cuts down the search space roughly by a factor of three as opposed to the factor of $q-1$ you get from dehomogenization.

Comment: Thank you! However, that only helps us in reducing the search of solutions in $\mathbb{F}_q$ and not with the choice of ideals. Do you have any idea regarding that?