# Solving $aX^3 + bY^3 + cZ^3 - dXYZ = 0$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: finite-fields, computational-complexity, cubics

I am looking for a way to solve the equation mentioned in the title with $Z\neq 0$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ without going through all $q^3$ possibilities. I was thinking: maybe we can reduce it to searching through only $q^2$ elements using which elements are cubes in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By homogeneity, you only need to search for the solutions where $Z=1$ or $Z=0$. (if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution with $z \neq 0$, then $(x/z,y/z,1)$ is a solution)

Comment: You probably can even reduce it, for large enough $q$, to the Weierstrass form of an equation, ie $u^2w=v^3+Avw^2+Bw^3$, and the same trick allows you to assume $w=1$, and then you search which $v^3+Av+B$ are squares.

Comment: Thankyou! I forgot about dehomogenization.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3714080/11619)? I'm sure you know that in general (barring singularities) this equation describes an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{F}_q$. While there are algorithms for finding the number of solutions (Schoof-Elkies-Atkin), I don't think you are really looking for that, so what do you really want to achieve here?